# NiFi | Controller Service is not getting updated

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

I created a sample controller service - 'MyControllerService' and packaged it into nar and pasted into nifi lib directory. I restarted nifi service to see changes. I was able to see MyControllerService in Controller setting. After that i made small label change into controller service and followed same process but changes are not getting affected.

Even i removed nar files from nifi/lib just to check if it getting removed from list. That too not happening.

Even I don't see any exception in nifi/log.

Any pointer for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential reason is that when starting up NiFi it will unpack the nars into the work directory. Try stopping the NiFi instance, removing the NIFI-HOME/work/ directory and starting NiFi again.

This should force the changes to take effect.